# Why does Google not want you to use C++ constructors?

Tags: c++, v8

```
     /**
     * A JavaScript value representing a signed integer.
     */
    class V8_EXPORT Integer : public Number {
     public:
      static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
      static Local<Integer> NewFromUnsigned(Isolate* isolate, uint32_t value);
      int64_t Value() const;
      V8_INLINE static Integer* Cast(v8::Value* obj);
     private:
      Integer();
      static void CheckCast(v8::Value* obj);
    };
```

The above code is from Google's V8 engine. Example initialization of this is:

```
Handle<Value> x = Integer::New(42);
```

From what I can see in the source code, they marked the constructor as private and want you to use the New function to create instances of this class. Isn't this against the standard C++ design patterns? Why didn't they just overload the constructor instead of making static functions for creation? This usually the kind of thing you see when people try to port a library from one language to another (the only one I can think of off the top of my head right now is Xamarin's iOS kit).

I've tried to Google around for a name for this type of convention but was unable to find anything on it really.

Comment: possibly because (wild guess here) integers and other primitive-related types are often pooled up to avoid constant creation of values?

Comment: Also note that the factory methods return a type that is different from what `new Integer(42)` would return. Think about that.

Comment: This technique is often called the "named constructor idiom" (because your (named) static member functions effectively replace constructors. In this case, look at the return type of `New`. It doesn't return an `Integer`, it returns a `Local<Integer>`. That's because they need to ensure that it can be mapped to the JavaScript it represents, so some additional bookkeeping is required, and that is implemented as a wrapper around Integer

Comment: There is no such a thing as "standard C++ design patterns".

Comment: Have a look at what the [Google Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml?showone=Doing_Work_in_Constructors#Doing_Work_in_Constructors) says about C++ constructors.  This may give you some clues as to their reasoning.

Comment: This is V8 code that is managing handles to memory in multiple heaps (the 'isolate' variable) that may be relocated in the future during garbage collection. Not really a normal situation in C++ or one where ordinary new/constructor practices fit well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pattern called "Static Factory Method", which is recommended by Joshua Bloch as Item 1 in "Effective Java". (I am almost sure that Scott Myers has an equivalent Item in "Effective C++", but right now I do not have a copy of the book to check.)

The advantages of creating objects through such a method, instead of the normal constructor, are described by Bloch as:

> - such methods may have a descriptive name
> - unlike constructors, such methods are *not required to create an entirely new object*, i.e. they can return a previously cached copy of
>     the object.
> - unlike constructors, such methods may also return an object of any subtype of their return type
> - such methods reduce verbosity of parameterized object construction

There are also downsides to this design pattern, it is only a recommendation in certain situations.

Probably, in the case of V8, the second point in the list is most important, in order to speed up construction. I am no V8 expert, but it seems that "event-driven, single-threaded" is its philosophy. When many "event callbacks" want to have one and the same number, all of them get a copy of the same instance of that number.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of handles. One of them is a "Local" handle. As shown in the code, local handles have the class `Handle<SomeType>`.

https://developers.google.com/v8/embed

> Note: The handle stack is not part of the C++ call stack, but the
>   handle scopes are embedded in the C++ stack. Handle scopes can only be
>   stack-allocated, not allocated with new.

https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started

> - A handle is a pointer to an object. All V8 objects are accessed using handles, they are necessary because of the way the V8 garbage
>     collector works.

Answer (score 2):

The most important reason to abstract away from low-level C++ constructors with factory methods is that allocation and construction need to be combined in this API. Most factory methods perform allocation. However, this allocation has to happen on the (garbage-colected) JavaScript heap, not the C++ heap. This has several consequences:

1. We cannot allow to construct raw objects without allocation, e.g. on the stack.
2. We cannot allow to use C++-side `new`.
3. We cannot allow to use raw pointers by default, because that would break garbage collection (handles are an indirection the GC is aware of and can update for relocation).

Factory methods help to enforce these restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Look's like they are using a static factory method. This can make sense when you want to centralize creation of objects because it must be done in a special way. I could imagine that the constructor provides a plain valid integer object and that the factory method than call additional methods to bring the object into a special initial state.

It is also a good idea to limit constructors to be as minimal as possible. Constructors should establish the invariant of the class. Additional settings can then be done by special methods, and creation of specifically initialized objects can be encapsulated in factories.

Comment: Good general guess, but I'm afraid the question is very specific about google's [tag:v8].